# Can I just use Bootstraps components and not layout system

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

My web application doesnt currently use Bootstrap or any other framework. I am now looking at making it more polished and realizing that the effect I want to achieve is quite Bootstrap like (i.e rounded buttons).

So if I now add Bootstrap to my website I have two questions

1. Will it leave my website unchanged until I start referring to Bootstrap components.
2. Can I use Bootstrap components without have to use the Bootstrap grid system
3. Can I override Bootstrap using CSS or do I have to use LESS which I dont understand

Comment: Q3 you can override Bootstrap with normal Css Only if your css file are loaded after bootstrap

Comment: Ps. Bootstrap 4 uses Sass, not LESS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Q 1.** Will it leave my website unchanged until I start referring to Bootstrap components.

**Ans:** Its totally depends on what classes, you have used in your HTML.
    For example if you have used **class="btn"** and then add bootstrap to your app, it will defiantly try to override the CSS, because Bootstrap has that class defined in its css file.

**Q 2**. Can I use Bootstrap components without have to use the Bootstrap grid system.

**Ans:** You can use Bootstrap components without using its Bootstrap grid, but if you are using bootstrap best is it properly,
        Because Grid system is something which provide your web app responsiveness.

**Q 3**: Can I override Bootstrap using CSS or do I have to use LESS which I dont understand

**Ans**: Yes you can.For example
        If you already have class

```
`.btn-primary{
        color: #eee;
        background-color: #337ab7;
        border-color: #2e6da4;
        border: 2px solid transparent;
        border-radius: 2px;
    }` in your app.
```

Then you added bootstrap and it also has this class in its library like:

```
`.btn-primary{
        color: #fff;
        background-color: #337ab7;
        border-color: #2e6da4;
        border: 1px solid transparent;
        border-radius: 4px;
    }`
    and overriding  your class.
```

So what you can do is, just use **!important** in your css for attribute which is conflicting. Like:

```
`.btn-primary{
        color: #eee !important;
        background-color: #337ab7;
        border-color: #2e6da4;
        border: 2px solid transparent !important;
        border-radius: 2px !important;
    }`
```

Now the HTML engine will always pick your CSS

Comment: Thanks, re Qu2. I do don't think the Bootstrap grid is going to let me do what I want, or if it does it will be take a while to understand so I just want to improve the look of my components at this point, Ive also added a Qu3

Comment: I am now trying Bootstrap I have found things mostly work but it has broken a few things (despite me not using any bootstrap class names) because boostrap redefines common standard elements classes (such as table)

Comment: That is right and thats why i suggested you to override bootstrap common standard elements with your own as per your need. There is no other way to tell bootstrap to ignore your elements

Comment: Yes, but for example i had table specific css it worked fine, it was only that bootstrap had changed the defaults for table that it broke things, and it was difficult to track down what it was in bootstrap that had broken it. This is very different than if I had a custom class that happened to have same as existing bootstrap class

Answer (score 1):

Q3: you can override it with higher specificity. That means if the your use the class btn from bootstrap you can add your own own class like my-btn and then reference it in your css like

```
.btn .my-btn{
    color:#123456;
}
```

Hope that helps

Comment: I think so the question was can I just regular CSS, and it seems that I can ?

Comment: yes, but you "need" an "override class" to achieve that goal

Comment: So if I just do .btn {color:#123456;} it won't replace all buttons with my new colour ?

Comment: Depending on two things: does your css get loaded first? does the css for btn from bootstrap have an !important on the color (which I don't think). You should never really use !important in css...

Comment: I can order by css to be added after, I havent added Bootstrapo yet IM trying to work out if the advanatges outweigh disadvantages

Comment: What you can do is just copy and modify the parts of bootstrap that you want to use into your own css file. This will safe loadtime and make your site quicker.

Comment: I definently don't want to do that, totally unmaintainable and would reuire me to relaly understand the Bootstrap files. After the first bootstrap load it will be cached anyway so dont think a major issue

Comment: Than I would recommend the BEM method with modifiers of existing classes (for maintainability) for example: .btn--color-grey will be used in css as follows `.btn .btn--color-grey{ color:grey; }`

Comment: Im not getting it, why I dont just override .btn-primary{
        color: #aaa;' , if I want it to be applied throughout my site why would I need to introduce a second class because then I have to remember to use two classes every time I add a button

Comment: If you use the same class, you just have to be careful concerning the order of css. It should work for most of bootstrap